# Update table from another table with a condition on a common column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to Mysql. I have a parent table with up to 3 children, I would like to update only the the first child from another child table with a condition.

Table `TblChild`

```
id_child - parent_id - child_name - child_number
```

Table `TblParent`

```
Id_paretn - parent_name - child_name_1 - child_id_1 - child_name_2 - child_id_2 - child_name_3 - child_id_3
```

Query

```
UPDATE TblParent
SET TblParent.child_name_1 = TblChild.child_name, 
    TblParent.child_id_1 = TblChild.child_id 
FROM TblChild, TblParent
WHERE TblParent.id_parent = TblChild.parent_id 
  AND TblChild.child_number = '1';
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you could use a update join

```
UPDATE TblParent
INNER JOIN TblChild ON  ( TblParent.id_parent = TblChild.parent_id 
                            AND TblChild.child_number = '1')
SET 
TblParent.child_name_1 = TblChild.child_name, 
TblParent.child_id_1 = TblChild.child_id
```